# how to set break for print page(div) using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <div id="print1">
                <%--content--%>
            </div>
            <div id="print2">
                <%--content--%>
            </div>
            <div id="print3">
                <%--content--%>
            </div>
```

i have to print the above div (print1, print2 and print3) but the problem is that contents of div print3 has too long. so, i have to set manually set where to break the page while printing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: Did it work? CSS Pagination support is very spotty in all browsers except dedicated HTML to PDF software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css -

```
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
```

[For more read this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)